# SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: (conn=63818) Access denied for user 'ravi'@'hostname' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, database-connection, resourcebundle, mysql-8.0

I am able to connect cloud mysql server if I use hardcoded without externalizing it `password=ravi@123` instead of the below, but at the moment I use the below format in order to use the value from the environment variable, it fails in spring boot. A hostname is our azure managed MySQL server host.

I googled enough *StackOverflow* solutions and tried multiple other options along with character encoding adding to connection string URL still no luck!

**characterEncoding=UTF-8**

```
url=jdbc:mysql://${mysql_host:hostname}:${mysql_port:3306}/ravidb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Could anybody help me to understand what I am missing? And what is the possible fix considering I have no option of modifying username or password?

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: development
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mariadb://${mysql_host:hostname}:${mysql_port:3306}/ravidb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: ${mysql_user:ravi@ravidb}
    password: ${mysql_password:ravi@123}
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
      connection-timeout: 20000
      idle-timeout: 300000
      max-lifetime: 1200000
      maximum-pool-size: 12
      minimum-idle: 5
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
        format_sql: true
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.3-groovy-2.5'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.24.0-GA'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    runtime 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.1'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
}
```

Comment: It is possible that you have some special characters that need  to be replaced to be recognized in password matching like / to // or " to /" or something like that. I had similar problems due to special characters in my password once. I know most SQL requires specialcharacters in the password to be approved, but try something basic like just adding a ! instead of multiple diffrent special characters. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered to see it worked if I just change key name `mysql_password` to `mysql_pass`

Issue reslved with this change:
`spring.datasource.password=${mysql_pass:ravi@123}`